# Duplicate key in ng-repeat when grouping

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the following [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter.git) to group my images by fullday. With the setup as below, I get the error:

> ngRepeat:dupes
>   Duplicate Key in Repeater Duplicates in a repeater are
>   not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
>   Repeater: (groupName, value) in images track by 'groupName'|
>   groupBy: 'fullday', Duplicate key: value.CID, Duplicate value:
>   {"CID":"CID-0.37998497346416116","year":2015,"month":2,"day":20,"fullday":"2015-2-20","time":"3:33
>   pm","notes":"","album":"No Album","favorite":false}

```
<ul ng-repeat="(groupName, value) in images track by 'value.CID' | groupBy: 'fullday'  ">

      <p>{{ groupName }}</p>

      <img 
        ng-repeat="imageInfo in value"
        ng-src="{{keygetThumbnail(value.CID)}}" 
        class="thumbnail-dash" 
        alt="Image"
        ng-click="goToViewer(imageInfo.CID)"
      >

    </ul>
```

How can I solve this? I tried adding `track by $index` but that does not work as it displays multiple image squares and not the image itself. Note that also all my `value.CID` are **unique** (in the object `images`)

Comment: Try removing the quotes around value.CID in track by expression

Comment: exactly, it treats the 'value.CID' as fixed string

Comment: Tried, but then what happens is that groupname becomes value.CID and I get per image 10 duplicates and the image is not shown...

Comment: What you want to achieve here is not very clear. You said that you need to group the images by date, but in the code you are grouping them by the property `time`. You want to group them by the property `fullday` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is a typo! Group by fullday, track by value.CID